# Stored procedure can not be called due to syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

We migrated from SQL Server to Postgres and I am trying to rewrite a stored procedure. The procedure is created correctly, but I can not call it.

This is my procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spr_getItems  ( 
  p_kind int = NULL,
  p_customerId varchar(256) = NULL,
  p_resourceIds varchar(2048) = NULL,
  p_referenceIds varchar(2048) = NULL
)
AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT
    c.kind,
    c.name AS customerName,
    c.oid AS customerId,
    r.name AS resourceName,
    r.oid AS resourceId
    o.fullObject AS fullObjectString
  FROM m_customer c
  JOIN m_resource r
    ON r.oid = c.resourceOid
  LEFT JOIN m_object o
    ON o.customerOid = c.oid
      AND o.customerOid = p_customerId
  WHERE (c.kind = p_kind OR p_kind is NULL)
    AND (c.referenceOid IN (SELECT refTemp.oid FROM tvf_commaSeperatedStringToTable(p_referenceIds) refTemp) OR p_referenceIds is NULL)
    AND (r.oid IN (SELECT resTemp.oid FROM tvf_commaSeperatedStringToTable(p_resourceIds) resTemp) OR p_resourceIds is NULL); 
END;
$$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

the table-valued-function `tvf_commaSeperatedStringToTable` just takes a string, splits it and returns a table with all of the different ids and a rownumber. It works just fine and is tested, no errors inside here.

Now when I try to execute it like this

```
CALL public.spr_getItems (0, null, null, null)
```

I get this output:

> ERROR: query has no destination for result data
>
> HINT: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
>   CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function spr_getItems(integer,character varying,character varying,character varying) line 3 at SQL statement
>   SQL state: 42601

But I do NOT want to discard the result, I want to see them.

So I tried calling it with select

```
SELECT * 
FROM CALL spr_getItems (0, null, null, null)
```

and then I get this syntax error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "0"
>   LINE 2:  0,
>            ^
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 40

I also tried executing it in several other way eg by adding the "public." before the procedures name, but then there has been a syntax error at the ".". Or with just using `select spr_getItems(0, null, null, null)` or `select spr_getItems(0)`, `select * from call spr_getItems (0)` and so on and so forth.

Am I doing something completely wrong and overlooked something in the documentation?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: clarification that I want to see the results
Edit2: accidentally copied a wrong function name
Edit3: added complete body as suggested

Comment: @Abelisto i do not want to discard the results.

Comment: The two answers so far have given you some good leads on how to fix this, but it seems you may also be using a procedure where you should be using a function.  If you want results from a stored bit of code, use a function.  `CALL` is used with procedures.  `SELECT` is used with functions.

Comment: @Jeremy As i said in my question, i only used mssql so far. There i used stored procedures to get one or more recordsets that i can use in my frontend. I will try use a function instead of a procedure and see what the results are. Afterwards i will go and lookup the difference between functions and stored procedures in postgres to get a better understanding of when to use what.Thank you

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added the procedures body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not  how Postgres works. Procedures aren't meant to return result sets.

If you want that use a set returning function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE function spr_getItems  ( 
  p_kind int = NULL,
  p_customerId varchar(256) = NULL,
  p_resourceIds varchar(2048) = NULL,
  p_referenceIds varchar(2048) = NULL
)
  returns table (kind text, customername text, customerid integer, resourcename text, resourceid integer, fullobjectstring text)
AS $$
  SELECT
    c.kind,
    c.name AS customerName,
    c.oid AS customerId,
    r.name AS resourceName,
    r.oid AS resourceId
    o.fullObject AS fullObjectString
  FROM m_customer c
  JOIN m_resource r
    ON r.oid = c.resourceOid
  LEFT JOIN m_object o
    ON o.customerOid = c.oid
      AND o.customerOid = p_customerId
  WHERE (c.kind = p_kind OR p_kind is NULL)
    AND (c.referenceOid IN (SELECT refTemp.oid FROM tvf_commaSeperatedStringToTable(p_referenceIds) refTemp) OR p_referenceIds is NULL)
    AND (r.oid IN (SELECT resTemp.oid FROM tvf_commaSeperatedStringToTable(p_resourceIds) resTemp) OR p_resourceIds is NULL); 
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

You also don't need PL/pgSQL for a simple query encapsulation, `language sql` will do just fine.

Then use it like a table:

```
select *
from spr_getitems(....);
```

Note that I guessed the data types in the `returns table (...)` part, you will have to adjust that to the real types used in your tables.

---

You don't need the sub-selects to handle the comma separated values either.

E.g. this:

```
AND (c.referenceOid IN (SELECT refTemp.oid FROM tvf_commaSeperatedStringToTable(p_referenceIds) refTemp) OR p_referenceIds is NULL)
```

can be simplified to

```
AND (c.referenceOid = any (string_to_array(p_referenceIds, ',')  OR p_referenceIds is NULL)
```

But passing multiple values as a comma separated string is bad coding style to begin with. You should declare those parameters as array and pass proper arrays to the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. But i would like to just call the procedure in my node js application like i did using the mssql library. i could just create a ConnectionPool there, start a request and give some input parameters. Then i just run execute on the procedure and get the results. Guess i will have to exchange that library anyway but just calling a procedure seems more convenient to me than to create select scripts and run those, even if they are very small. Again, thanks! Found an article to lookup the difference of stored procedures and functions in postgres.

Comment: You will have to change your calling code. Selecting from the function is the same as selecting from a table - why is running a SELECT so "inconvenient" in that library? Does it not support running SELECT statements?

Comment: This library is only for mssql. i will use a postgres library that is similar to it (pg or postgres, i think. not sure yet). both support running SELECT statements. i just meant that i have been able to use something like that: `pool.request().input('param1', value1).input('param2', value2).execute('spr_name' (err, result) => { /* do something */ }` which in my opinion is very readable. using the pg library the syntax would now be like `pool.query('SELECT * FROM spr_name ($1, $2)', [value1,value2], (err, res) => { /* do something */ })`. Seems like a little bit less code but also less readable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
EXEC spr_getItems p_kind = 0,
  p_customerId = NULL,
  p_resourceIds = NULL,
  p_referenceIds = NULL
```

Comment: just tried it... ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXEC"
LINE 1: EXEC spr_getItems (0, null, null, null);
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1

Comment: There is no `exec` in Postgres

Answer (score 0):

The error refers to a function call (**spr_getshadowrefs**) inside the **public.spr_getItems** procedure. Perhaps you're trying to execute the **spr_getshadowrefs** function without putting the result in any variable.

Try to use PERFORM when you execute the **spr_getshadowrefs** function inside the **public.spr_getItems** procedure.

Comment: He should not to "use PERFORM when you execute that function" but use PERFORM at line 3 of that function's body BTW.

Comment: "CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function spr_getshadowrefs(integer,character varying,character varying,character varying) line 3 at SQL statement" means that error occurred **inside** function `spr_getshadowrefs`, not while the calling it.

Comment: Oh you're right! So, is there a **SELECT** statement inside **spr_getshadowrefs** function that doesn't give a value to any variable? If would be helpful if he could provide us some code of the procedure.<br> PD: use **CALL public.spr_getItems ( 0, null, null, null)**

Comment: @JuanCarlosYupanquiLozano Sorry i accidentally copied a wrong function name that has been open in another query, same error though. i do not call a function inside of a function. My bad but thank you for trying to help!